# Error estimation of maximum likelihood fit in zfit with weight

Tags: zfit

I am looking at the zfit tutorial, and seeing the comment about the likelihood with weight, (see attached image)

[image]

does anyone know if how the uncertainty is estimated in this case. How would the weight contribute here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A weighted likelihood is indeed not a "real likelihood" anymore, however, the point estimation at the maximum is still valid.

The method implemented in zfit is the "asymptotically correct approach"as described in [Parameter uncertainties in weighted unbinned maximum likelihood fits](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-022-10254-8).

It will be taken into account automatically if your dataset is weighted.

*(since this info was missing in the `hesse` docs, it just got updated)*